# Windows does not recognize the full capacity of my hitachi harddrive

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

After some digging my real question turned out to be why windows only recognized roughly half the size of my hard drive. My original text:

On my 2 TB data disk I have two primary partitions, one of 1.6 TB for data storage in Linux (ext3) and one of 300 GB for some additional data storage for Windows. I run a dual-boot Windows 7/Ubuntu 12.04 install.

The issue I have that if I start my computer into Windows 7, bot the partitions on my 2TB data drive are not recognized. In stead, Windows 7 sees one 1TB partition with type RAW. However, if I reboot to Linux, and then back to Windows 7, the partitions are correctly recognized.

The following two screenshots illustrate my situation. Before I reboot to linux:

[image]

and after the reboot:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. What could cause this behavior?
2. How can I solve this issue.

Edit:
The following two changes did not solve the issue:
 1. I replaced the grub bootloader by the standard windows 7 bootloader
 2. I replaced the two partitions on the data drive by one ntfs partition.

So the system is now a single boot windows 7 system, and it still does not recognize the 2 tb ntfs partition, but insists that it is a 950 gb RAW partition.

Edit:
When I removed the partition with gparted in ubuntu, Windows saw unpartitioned space, but only 950 GB (roughly half the size).

Comment: I take it that if after your first boot into Windows and you see the 1TB Raw Partition rebooting into Windows causes it to still show as 1TB RAW, it is *only* rebooting into Linux that fixes this?

Comment: Rebooting to Windows does not solve the problem, only rebooting to linux, and then back to Windows fixes the issue.

Comment: Hmm, if booting into Linux before booting into Windows makes it work, but then rebooting into Windows again makes it stop working, then obviously something in the Windows boot (loader, autorun, etc.) is writing something incorrect to the disk (partition table, boot-sector, etc.) Try disabling all autorun programs, reboot into Linux and back to Windows, then  Windows again. If it is still RAW, then you need to examine your Windows boot files. You said you replaced GRUB with the Windows bootloader; how exactly did you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the issue was that Windows only recognized half of my disk. After some digging (and some more digging) I found out this is a problem which can occur because of a [host protected area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area) (HPA). Using `hdparm`, included with the Linux partitioning tool `gparted`, I can check if this is the case. From an Ubuntu live CD I issued the following commands:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo hdparm -N /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 max sectors   = 1953569134/3907029168, HPA is enabled
```

If I check my other disk it shows this output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo hdparm -N /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 max sectors   = 156301488/156301488, HPA is disabled
```

which shows what I would expect, all the sectors on the hard drive are visible. So it seems that half of the sectors on my 2 TB disk under /dev/sdb are covered by an HPA. The following hdparm command fixed this:

```
sudo hdparm -N p3907029168 /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
 setting max visible sectors to 3907029168 (permanent)
 max sectors   = 3907029168/3907029168, HPA is disabled
```

by setting the maximum visible sectors to the maxmimum of the drive, and thus disabling the HPA. Now if I go to Windows and check Disk management, the disk nicely shows the correct amount of free space.

It could be that the HPA is caused by my gigabyte motherboard which hides a copy of the bios in a HPA on a harddrive. A bug in the bios causes this HPA to cut the space on this two Tb hard drive in two, see also [this post on tom's hardware](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/255691-14-bought-drive-bios-detect). The information is roughly halfway down the replies, by a user called fzabkar. The OP in that post also used a hitachi drive, so it could be that the problem is caused by a combination of a Gigabyte motherboard and a Hitachi hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

RAW partitions are usually created and recognized in *nix-based systems. Example: The Informix RDBMS creates a raw disk partition in order to bypass the *nix-based OS and directly manage disk allocation and access for improved performance. It creates a symbolic-link (ln) for the rhd device. Although Windows Vista and newer versions support hard-links with the mklink.exe command, Windows alone will not recognize an *nix-created RAW disk partition. It would probably show up as "Unallocated Space" under Windows.

I have Ubuntu 12.04-LTS installed within the WinVista-SP2, NTFS C: partition. During install, I told it to reserve 80GB of the C: partition for Ubuntu, and can shrink the 80GB to add a raw disk partition. When I boot my computer, it asks me if I want to boot into Windows or Ubuntu, plus I can share data between the two OS's with a Multiple Domain-like feature. This version of Ubuntu has its own virtualization.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-can-i-get-windows-7-to-read-raw-hard-drives/fa425072-72d9-4e4c-b80b-98a3882319b2

Comment: My problem is not reading a RAW partition, but that windows mistakenly sees a RAW partition.

Comment: Perhaps its a cosmetic bug since the non-NTFS raw partition may not comform to GUID Partition Table (GPT) spec? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx  .. but as long as everything is there, don't worry and be happy that it didn't get clobbered :)

Comment: There are two ways of installing U12.04, along side Windows, within the NTFS partition (which I did) and in a separate partition (you did).. Both options offer dual boot at post time. Perhaps if you installed 12.04 within NTFS and created the raw partition for 12.04, it would be visible when booting Win7?